# Read Component Inside Span

Tags: javascript, html

I need to read `Objectname`'s values inside `<span></span>` but I try read it using `innerHTML` and I get "---"

Where am I going wrong?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<span id="testing" COMPONENTNAME="binarystatus" SITENAME="ABC" OBJECTNAME="TRIP ALARM" OBJECTTYPE="3">---</span>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `Objectname's values`? If you mean the attributes of the `<span>` then `innerHTML` is not the way to go, you'll need to use [getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) instead.

Comment: thxz for your fast response. i try with get attributes

Comment: It working perfectly!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**innerHTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) returns a string representation of the serialized HTML within the element instead but does not query the value of the  `OBJECTNAME` attribute.

If you want to read the attribute value of `OBJECTNAME` you could use [**getAttribute**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) instead.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("testing").getAttribute("OBJECTNAME");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<span id="testing" COMPONENTNAME="binarystatus" SITENAME="ABC" OBJECTNAME="TRIP ALARM" OBJECTTYPE="3">---</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

try the below code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("testing").attributes.objectname.value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<span id="testing" COMPONENTNAME="binarystatus" SITENAME="ABC" OBJECTNAME="TRIP ALARM" OBJECTTYPE="3">---</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call:

```
the_span.getAttribute("OBJECTNAME")
```